# How to find beginning of the previous month using tm struct?

Tags: c++, datetime, time

I have simple question: how to convert my `timestampS` variable to beginning of the previous month?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::string timestampS="2022-03-31T17:29:27Z";
    std::tm tm2;
    strptime(timestampS.c_str(),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &tm2);
    tm2.tm_mon=tm2.tm_mon-1;
    tm2.tm_mday=1;
    tm2.tm_hour=0;
    tm2.tm_min=0; 
    tm2.tm_sec=0; 
    std::cout << std::asctime(&tm2);
}
```

Output

`Thu Feb  1 00:00:00 2022`

It works ok only if last month is in this same year.

Comment: If `tm_mon` is `-1`, add `12` and decrease the year.

Comment: Do you know how to write an `if` statement? This should not be difficult. You need to detect the case where this month is January, and in that case select December of the previous year; otherwise use the previous month as you have done in the question. Or use the logic described by @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

Could test if `tm2.tm_mon < 0` and then adjust: [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69842814/how-to-find-begining-of-the-previous-month-using-tm-struct/69843110#comment123458579_69842814)

```
tm2.tm_mon = tm2.tm_mon - 1;
if (tm2.tm_mon < 0) {
  tm2.tm_mon += 12;
  tm2.tm_year--;
}
```

**or**

For general `struct tm` adjustments, on local time<sup>1</sup>,  use [`mktime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).  It will re-adjust members to their primary range.  Be sure to set all members and  `.tm_isdst`.

```
// std::tm tm2;
std::tm tm2 = { 0 }; 
strptime(timestampS.c_str(),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &tm2);
tm2.tm_isdst = -1;
tm2.tm_mon = tm2.tm_mon-1;
tm2.tm_mday = 1;
tm2.tm_hour = 0;
tm2.tm_min = 0; 
tm2.tm_sec = 0;
mktime(&tm2);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The `Z` in the string implies [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)).